# Android app always crash when recieve push notification from Pusher

Tags: android, kotlin, pusher

I'm just trying to implement a simple Pusher beam notification from Pusher. i did a quick start from Pusher. I configured and added dependencies and stuff but whenever i use the curl command to try to send notification . it always crash . I've been trying to find the solution for hours but couldn't find it. It's driving me crazy . please help.

Here is my code in
MainActivitiy.kt

```
    PushNotifications.start(this, "instance id")
    PushNotifications.addDeviceInterest("hello")
```

here's the log :

```
 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Firebase-WrappedFirebaseMessagingService
Process: com.example.azda, PID: 22200
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.content.Context.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getSystemService(ContextWrapper.java:562)
    at com.google.firebase.messaging.zzd.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@@20.0.0:10)
    at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.zzc(com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@@20.0.0:60)
    at com.google.firebase.messaging.zze.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@@20.0.0:2)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.util.concurrent.zza.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: Hello! Try to provide application context against activity instance.

Comment: thanks for replying , I already put (applicationContext,"instance-id") but it's still pose the same error .

Answer (score 0):

I found it . The problem is i shouldn’t use kotlin syntax of applicationContext when the solution is to use getApplicationContext() like in java .

Spent 10 hours just to write 2 lines of code . Felt so worthless and wanted to kill myself . Goddamn